# How to get or parse parameter from onitemdatabound method

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have method:

```
protected void DormatItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
```

sender object have `DataSource` which is type of - `object {Sitecore.Collections.ChildList}`

Now I want get data from this DataSource object but when I try using intelisense I see only 4 methods (probably object methods):

- Equals
- GetHashCode
- GetType
- ToString

---

### Question:

So the question is what I should to do to using this **sender** as a `{Sitecore.Collections.ChildList}` object?

It will be easy for people who have more experience than me.

Comment: that would be probably a safe cast if you sure that **sender** is a type you want.

Comment: yes. If you want put it as answer or I will do it. I just test this solution and it works. I should try it before put my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably use **as** operator to deal with safe cast.

```
protected void DormatItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = sender as Sitecore.Collection.Childlist;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        // To do here
    }
}
```